# Can a Nepalese (Asian) open a bank account in US without visiting there?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, small-business, nepal

I am living in Nepal (South Asia) and want to setup a business using which Nepalese living in the USA can pay for gifts and services to be delivered here in Nepal to their beloved ones. To receive such payments in US how can I open a bank account there sitting right here from Nepal? I have been not able to find a really helpful answer on this from long.  (Banks here do not have much stronger network there, however people use remittance services like Western Union, etc to send money across.)

Answer (score 1):

Western Union is one way to send emergency cash to a family member. It seems suspicious as a method of goods payment because many frauds have used it as a means of collecting irreversible payments.

EBay and Paypal would be a better more trustworthy way to sell to usa customers.

Most USA banks need a USA address for the account owner..... But you may not need a USA bank account as PayPal can store and exchange funds to other currencies.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. For Paypal, I will need a credit card number. So will my credit/debit card (issued by a Nepalese Bank) work with Paypal to let me withdraw payments here?

Comment: @YogeshAggrawal From what I understand, to withdraw payments, you'll need to integrate Paypal with your bank account. I don't know if your bank is supported by Paypal, you'll have to try it and find out. I believe they can also mail you a check if that doesn't work out, which should work regardless.